# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare social_connect_get_user_by_meta()

Tags: wordpress

I wanted to install a social plugin in wordpress and got the following error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare social_connect_get_user_by_meta() (previously declared in /home/lilycoll/public_html/wp-content/themes/ProjectTheme/lib/social/utils.php:4) in /home/lilycoll/public_html/wp-content/plugins/social-connect/utils.php on line 9

Comment: please anyone need help.

Comment: The error is very clear: your theme has the same function as the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try resetting your plugins and test again?

You can refer to a similar issue here :

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-metadata_exists-wp-includescapabili